# Resume from Suspend/Hibernate issues

Tags: kernel, suspend, assembly

I have a peculiar problem while trying to resume from both suspend and hibernate. I believe the problem to be within the kernel itself since I have tried different distros (Ubuntu, Suse, Mageia) on different kernel version (12,13,16) with different GPU drivers.

Suspend works, if for a short time. If the machine is asleep for a long duration (shortest I've seen is 90 minutes but may be less) it will not resume. When I say won't resume I don't mean the usual power on but no screen, I mean the chassis fan LED will flash once and nothing will power up. In addition, neither the reset button nor holding the power button work. I have to physically cut the power, wait for the capacitors to discharge then power on.

All of the suspends are issued from the shell (not GUI) using pm-suspend. I've tried the pm_trace method, looked into the logs and found a "Magic number" but there was no "hash matches" entry.

I've tried adding ALL modules to `/etc/default/acpi-support` and the problem persists.

It's almost as if the system clock is overwriting something.

My system specs:
Asus M4A78LT-LE mainboard with latest BIOS.
ATI Radeon HD6790 GPU.
AMD Phenom 2 X4 965 Processor

**Update:**
I now need to try a custom kernel as stated in [this ubuntu reference](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Reference/S3) to detect if the BIOS is jumping back into the kernel. To do this I need to modify the `arch/x86/kernel/acpi/wakeup_64.S` file to emit a series of system beeps. The problem, I do not know Assembler. I need this for the 3.13.0 kernel, which I know to work on my system, and targeted for AMD 64.

If the problem is indeed the BIOS not jumping back, how might I correct it?

Comment: Do you have a chance to check it on another machine with exactly the same parts? No, but it would show more, if the buggy behaviour us reproducible on the certain hardware, that can be interpreted as a Kernel/Drives - software bug.

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov Unfortunately I don't.